# Python Connect to IRC via tor

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.5, irc, tor

Does it possible to connect IRC via tor ?

Below my code for IRC server connection:

```
    connection = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    connection.connect((self.server, self.port))
    connection.send(
        'USER {nickname} {nickname} {nickname} {nickname}\n'.format(nickname=self.nickname).encode('utf-8')
    )
    connection.send('NICK {nickname}\n'.format(nickname=self.nickname).encode('utf-8'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

connecting via [SOCKS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCKS) that [Tor exposes](https://www.marcus-povey.co.uk/2016/03/24/using-tor-as-a-http-proxy/) is probably the easiest way.

the Python library [PySocks](https://github.com/Anorov/PySocks) works for me, install with the normal:

```
pip install -U PySocks
```

then do:

```
import socks

# assuming your Tor client is using the defaults
socks.set_default_proxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, 'localhost', 9150)
```

you can then make TCP connections as normal using the `socks.socksocket` class, which will cause the actual connection to go via Tor

```
import socket

with socks.socksocket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.connect(('chat.freenode.net', 6667))
    s.send('USER {0} {0} {0} {0}\r\n'.format(nickname).encode('utf8'))
    s.send('NICK {0}\r\n'.format(nickname).encode('utf8'))
    print(s.recv(4096).decode('utf8'))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm using pycharm and after installing pysocks libraries do not updated for IDE. So, I can import socks using simple console, but can't do this through pycharm. Can you help me with this issue ?

Comment: sorry, I live at the command line… google suggests [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html) for "pycharm install package"

Comment: `socks.ProxyConnectionError: Error connecting to SOCKS5 proxy localhost:9150: [Errno 111] Connection refused`

I'm getting this error, how to fix it ?. Tor is running on my system.

Comment: you need to figure out where your tor client is exposing itself…  the second link in my answer has a description, if you're using the TBB check its network settings

Comment: Sure, I edit `socks.set_default_proxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, 'localhost', 9150)` string replacing port with 9050, because 9050 is defaults. Now I getting another error: `OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor` on socket.recv

Comment: a `with` block automatically closes it's file descriptor when it exits, so you can't use it after the block has finished executing.  might be worth reading up on ["context managers"](https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2016/03/07/python-with-context-managers/)

Comment: It seems IRC do not allow connection via TOR. Does it possible to hide tor connection ?

Comment: sorry…  maybe ask with the IRC operator?